# How do I make each group within a dataframe the same size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lstm

I have the following dataframe:

| Patient | HR | 02 | PaO2 | Hgb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 62 | 94 | 73 | 31 |
| 1 | 64 | 93 | 73 | 34 |
| 1 | 62 | 92 | 73 | 31 |
| 2 | 64 | 90 | 84 | 42 |
| 3 | 62 | 95 | 75 | 30 |
| 3 | 70 | 97 | 77 | 29 |

Each row for a patient indicates an hourly observation. So, patient 1 has three observations, patient 2 has one observation and patient 3 has two observations. I'm trying to find a way to pad each patient group so that they are the same size (the same number of observations) as I'm trying to use this data for an LSTM. I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be though. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

The output would hopefully look like this:

| Patient | HR | 02 | PaO2 | Hgb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 62 | 94 | 73 | 31 |
| 1 | 64 | 93 | 73 | 34 |
| 1 | 62 | 92 | 73 | 31 |
| 2 | 64 | 90 | 84 | 42 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 62 | 95 | 75 | 30 |
| 3 | 70 | 97 | 77 | 29 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: is there an hour column?

Comment: Pad with what? Can you include your expected output?

Comment: There isn't an hour column in the dataframe @Umar.H

Comment: @not_speshal I've edited the question, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reindex your original data to a `pandas.MultiIndex` on the Patient and Cumulative Count:

```
df = df.set_index(["Patient", df.groupby("Patient").cumcount()])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
output = df.reindex(index, fill_value=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()

>>> output
   Patient  HR  02  PaO2  Hgb
0        1  62  94    73   31
1        1  64  93    73   34
2        1  62  92    73   31
3        2  64  90    84   42
4        2   0   0     0    0
5        2   0   0     0    0
6        3  62  95    75   30
7        3  70  97    77   29
8        3   0   0     0    0
```